# Append LINE FEED in VIM repeatedly after a line containing a unique String

Tags: bash, perl, vim, awk

Is there a way to append LINEFEED after every line containing the String

"Specialty" here are example of some lines:

```
"XYZ_Specialty=1122"
"Specialty_123=AABB"
"Specialty_MOD=ZZZZ"
```

Now, all the above three lines contain "Specialty" and i would like to append LINEFEED in linux after the end of line , as in right after :

```
1122
AABB
ZZZZ
```

If not in vim,perhaps in perl , or bash / awk ?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: i'm not the downvoter but i know the reason for the downvote. I think it's probably because of lack of attempts.

Comment: i don't know how `XYZ_Specialty=1122` turns to `1122` after adding the linefeed character at the last.

Comment: it does not turn into 1122, rather a linefeed (o in vim) is appended to the line "Specialty_MOD=ZZZZ", or "XYZ_Specialty=1122", and after the LINEFEED is added to the line containing the string "Specialty" it just shows up as blank lines:

Comment: Your question is far from clear. You want a linefeed inserted before the closing quotation mark in all lines that contain `Specialty`? If you are having a problem with doing this yourself, then please show what you have tried and we will help you to fix it.

Comment: i actually found the answer, but i want to add a linefeed after the line with the text Specialty_MOD=ZZZZ ignore the Quotation marks

Comment: @kamal: I thought it was *any* line containing `Specialty`? And what do you mean by *"ignore the Quotation marks"*? Do you want the linefeed inserted *before* or *after* them?

Comment: ignore the quotation means, the Quotations are there to indicate the whole string, so ignore "" like they dont exist the text as it appears in the file is XYZ_Specialty=1122 and i need the linefeed right after the last 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if it is what you need, yet you can use `sed` in `bash`. I also assume that your data is stored in a file called `temptest2`

```
sed "s/\(.*Specialty.*\)\"/\1\n/g" temptest2
```

- Use `-i` to save the output to the `temptest2`
- () specify a field for you, which is being called by \1 and then sed adds `\n` to the end of it.